# cypress testing - server sent events mocking

Tags: cypress, server-sent-events

I am trying to setup a E2E cypress test
And for the same, trying(but **FAILED**) to get the events from the SSE connection(mocked) and for the same emitting the push event before setting the SSE connection
Q: Can you please help to sort this out, as I **might be doing the whole thing wrong or missing something**

Note: as per this PR, cypress supports SSE - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/2054
Not able to find any reference on cypress for SSE support - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html

```
const EEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

```
        cy.route({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `**/documentprocessing/startprocess`,
            status:200,
            response: {
                "uniqueId": "abcd12345677",
            },

        })
            .as(`startprocess`)
            .route({
                method: 'GET',
                status:200,
                url: '**/documentprocessing/getSSEStatus/**',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                    Connection: 'keep-alive',
                },
                onResponse: () => {
                    EEmitter.on('push', function(event, data) {
                        response.write(
                            'event: ' +
                            String(event) +
                            'data: ' +
                            String(data) +,
                        );
                    });
                }
            })
            .as(`sseStatus`);
```

In the below code, after 1st API call(@startprocess), emitting push events

Then trying to get push events in response (in @sseStatus call above)

```
cy.route(`@startprocess`);
setTimeout(function() {
            EEmitter.emit('push','message', { 'uniqueId':'abcd12345677' ,'uploadStatus':'Started'});
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            EEmitter.emit('push','message', { 'uniqueId':'abcd12345677' ,'uploadStatus':'Complete'});
        }, 3000);
 cy.wait(3000)
 cy.wait(`@sseStatus`);
```

Comment: Did you manage to mock SSE requests? If yes please post an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I needed to mock a api call with `text/event-stream` as the content type.

I have mocked api calls using json fixtures in the past easy stuff you just do something like

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/endpoint?*', { fixture: 'folder/my-json.json' }).as('my-api-call');
```

but with `text/event-stream` I had to do it a little different (keep in mind this is what I did, it doesn't mean it is the best way to do it, since I couldn't find anything in the oficial documentation)

```
import json from 'path/to/myjson.json'

cy.intercept('GET', '/endpoint*', (req) =>
  req.reply(`data: ${JSON.stringify(json)} \n\n`,
   {
      'content-type': 'text/event-stream'
   }
)).as('my-api-call');
```